# var set to nil even if find_by returns something else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I run `pry-debugger` to find out why my controller doesn't work as desired. I set a breakpoint at 76th line:

```
    70: def move
    71:   binding.pry
    72:   @moved_slides = []
    73:     @ids.each do |id|
    74:       begin
    75:         @slide = Slide.find_by(id: id)
 => 76:         @moved_slides << @slide.album_id = @new_album_id
    77:       rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    78:         flash_message :error, "Cannot move #{id} slide."
    79:       end
```

and there is something strange which I don't understand at line 75. For some reason `@slide` is set to `nil` even if `Slide.find_by(id: id)` returns something else:

```
[20] pry(#<SlidesController>)> id
=> "5"
[21] pry(#<SlidesController>)> @slide        
=> nil
[22] pry(#<SlidesController>)> Slide.find_by(id: id)
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "slides".* FROM "slides" WHERE "slides"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "slides"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
=> #<Slide id: 5, album_id: 5, description: "", created_at: "2014-05-08 13:34:47", updated_at: "2014-05-08 13:34:47", photo_file_name: "DSC_2382.JPG", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 1831664, photo_updated_at: "2014-05-08 13:34:47", photo_fingerprint: "c01877ee5d98b1fa456bb174741aef39", deleted_at: nil, photo_processing: true>
```

btw: I know I should use `find_by!` rather `find_by` if I want to get `RecordNotFound` but this is not the case here.

Comment: Why not to use `find` if it's `id`

Comment: Can you try - `@slide = Slide.find_by(id: id.to_i)` ?

Comment: @zishe: good point! I'm very beginner and for some unknown reason I end-up with the `find_by`. I just changed it to `Slide.find(id)` but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: 1. Your rescue statement will never execute. 2. What exactely were your steps in pry console? Are you sure assignment already took place?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: tried `Slide.find(id.to_i)` - doesn't change anything.

Comment: It is a *Lolllz* issue.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the value of `@slide` before it is assigned. Try:

```
def move
  @moved_slides = []
  @ids.each do |id|
    begin
      @slide = Slide.find_by(id: id)
      binding.pry
      @moved_slides << @slide.album_id = @new_album_id
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      flash_message :error, "Cannot move #{id} slide."
    end
  end
end
```

And you'll see all is fine.

Comment: I didn't run `continue` after `break 76` and `=>` mark tricked me :) This is very first time I'm using `pry-debugger`

Comment: @pawel7318 - Well, this look like pry-debugger bug. I would raise an issue on github for this if I were you. :)

Comment: probably it's not - I merged output of `binding.pry` with `break 76` here so `=>` mark showed just where the breakpoint was set.. Btw. is there a way to re-list the code with current position marked ?

Comment: Now I find it -> `whereami`